# Not able to click on a button on website using VBA

Tags: vba

Hi i am trying to click a button on a website using vba.
Here is the html tag lines. I tried calling it by using **getelementsbytagname("inputAdd")** but it throws error.
Here is the html tags:

```html
<div class="configurableStyle" id="configurabled12">
  <h1>Add To Cart</h1>
  <div class="inner-section">
    <p>The product you are adding to the Cart may require Configuration.
      <br>The Prices do not reflect valid Prices
    </p>
    <input class="marginR10" onclick='configureNonUCS("WS-C2960S-48FPS-L", 6595, $(".configurableQty12").val(), 0, "Catalyst 2960S 48 GigE PoE 740W, 4 x SFP LAN Base");' type="button" value="Configure"><a class="addCart" onclick='addNonUCSToCart(null, "WS-C2960S-48FPS-L", 6595.00,$(".configurableQty12").val(), 0, "Catalyst 2960S 48 GigE PoE 740W, 4 x SFP LAN Base","N","Y","1","Y","null")' href="javascript://">
    Add to Cart and Configure later</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the VBA code:

```
intStart = InStr(1, strSubHTML, "WS-C2960S-24TD-L", vbTextCompare) + 1 
intStart = InStr(intStart, strSubHTML, "WS-C2960S-24TD-L", vbTextCompare)
objCollection = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("addCart") 
Set form = ie.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("configurableQty12")(0) 
Set Button = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0) 
Button.Click
```

Comment: Here is the html of the website:

Comment: But we also (and especially) need the code in VBA that doesn't work.

Comment: intStart = InStr(1, strSubHTML, "WS-C2960S-24TD-L", vbTextCompare) + 1
    intStart = InStr(intStart, strSubHTML, "WS-C2960S-24TD-L", vbTextCompare)
    objCollection = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("addCart")


    
    Set form = ie.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("configurableQty12")(0)
    Set Button = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0)
    Button.Click

Comment: The click event is the one which i am not able to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems, I will highlight the two that should fix it but it's still to be tested:

### Objects in VBA must be set through the keyword `Set`

You have a collection defined as follows in your code:

```
objCollection = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("addCart")
```

this line of code will most probably raise an error because `objCollection` is supposed to be a collection, hence it should rather be:

```
Set objCollection = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("addCart")
```

### There's no tag `<button>` in the HTML you're giving us

You're trying to define your button as the first element of the collection of `<button>` objects in the HTML document:

```
Set Button = ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")(0)
```

However, as far as I see, there's no element which has tag `<button>` in the HTML snippet you gave us. Maybe, you've seen that the `type` property of the `<input>` object is `button` and you get confused. 
To correctly set the button, you should rather use:

```
Set Button = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(0)
```

But be warned that the above assumes the button being the *first input element* of the page, which I doubt as soon as the page as a header containing a login form or a search engine. Hence, what you might do is to loop through the inputs and click the one having value *Configure*:

```
Set AllButtons = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each button In AllButtons
    If button.value = "Configure" Then
        button.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next button
```

Comment: Please note: the two aboves _might be_ two fixes, but you should debug a bit yourself cause there might be other problems in your code.

Comment: In this case how can I check button is active or inactive? is there a way to check the button condition.